# Add library to build path with Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have added `java.smartcardio` library via `right click > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Module Dependencies` manually to my Eclipse project.

Anyway, after `right click > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project` the library gets removed again from build path.

.classpath when working:

```
...
<classpathentry ...>
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
    <attribute name="limit-modules" value="java.se,jdk.accessibility,jdk.httpserver,jdk.jartool,jdk.javadoc,jdk.jconsole,jdk.jshell,jdk.jsobject,jdk.management.jfr,jdk.naming.ldap,jdk.net,jdk.scripting.nashorn,jdk.sctp,jdk.security.auth,jdk.security.jgss,jdk.unsupported,jdk.unsupported.desktop,jdk.xml.dom,java.smartcardio"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
...
```

.classpath after refreshing Gradle:

```
...
<classpathentry ...>
</classpathentry>
...
```

Setting limit-modules manually in project.gradle like

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                def jre = entries.find { it.path.contains 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER' }
                jre.entryAttributes['module'] = 'true'
                jre.entryAttributes['limit-modules'] = 'java.se,java.smartcardio'           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

did not work, because strangly every developer has limit-modules filled differently when added the library manually.

Any hint how to solve that permanently?

Edit: I found this thread https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/760, which is describing the same issue but did not solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion,
I have modified your code and it seems to work in jdk 17

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                def jre = entries.find { it.path.contains 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER' }
                jre.entryAttributes['module'] = 'true'
                jre.entryAttributes['limit-modules'] = 'java.se,jdk.accessibility,jdk.dynalink,jdk.httpserver,jdk.jartool,jdk.javadoc,jdk.jconsole,jdk.jshell,jdk.jsobject,jdk.management.jfr,jdk.net,jdk.nio.mapmode,jdk.sctp,jdk.security.auth,jdk.security.jgss,jdk.unsupported,jdk.unsupported.desktop,jdk.xml.dom,java.smartcardio'
                jre.entryAttributes['add-modules'] = 'java.smartcardio'           //--limit-modules java.se --add-modules java.smartcardio
              }
          }
       }
   }
```